# Importing KML to GeoServer?

Tags: python, geoserver, kml, geoserver-rest-api

**Update**

It appears I cannot upload KML files to GeoServer, even if I use the Importer Web Interface.

Using the "Import Data" web interface, I tried to manually add the KML file to GeoServer. I moved my KML file onto the server, then used the "Import Data" interface as follows:

1. Choose a data source to import from

   - Spatial Files
2. Configure the data source

   - Choose a file or directory: `/var/lib/opengeo/geoserver/data/amallard/myFMLfile.kml`
3. Specify the target for the import

   - Workspace: `amallard`
   - Store: `Create New`

When I clicked "Next" I got an error

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No features found`

And this traceback in the error log:

```
2017-02-28 19:24:02,183 WARN [importer.web] - 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No features found
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.geoserver.importer.web.ImportDataPage$4$1.onTimer(ImportDataPage.java:221)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.respond(AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior.java:159)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:300)
...
...
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No features found
at org.geoserver.importer.format.KMLFileFormat.parseFeatureTypes(KMLFileFormat.java:230)
at org.geoserver.importer.format.KMLFileFormat.parseFeatureTypes(KMLFileFormat.java:156)
at org.geoserver.importer.format.KMLFileFormat.list(KMLFileFormat.java:252)
...
...
at org.geoserver.importer.Importer$2.call(Importer.java:305)
at org.geoserver.importer.job.Job.call(Job.java:16)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
... 3 more
```

Full traceback can be [seen here](http://adamallard.net/error1.txt) - (I cannot embed the entire error log traceback in here because then my post exceeds the maximum amount of characters.)

I received this error with 2 KML files that most certainly do have features. I used a third, [sample KML file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml) that did upload, however, upon previewing it with OpenLayers (inside GeoServer) there was nothing there.

**KML Files I've tried**

[KML1](http://adamallard.net/kml1.kml) - doesn't upload
[KML2](http://adamallard.net/kml2.kml) - doesn't upload
[KML3](http://adamallard.net/kml3.kml) - uploads but doesn't display in OpenLayers - open it in Google Earth and it doesn't display either. But I can open and view the file as is in Google Earth before I even upload it to GeoServer

**Original Post**

I've read in numerous places that you can import KML files into GeoServer. (Our current system converts KML files to SHP before uploading to GeoServer, but that doesn't always work the best so we're trying to upload the KML files directly).

I understand that this should be possible with the GeoServer Importer Extension, but I am having no luck of getting the REST API calls right.

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = { 
    "import": {
        "targetWorkspace":{
            "workspace":{
                "name": username
            }
        },
        "targetStore":{
            "dataStore":{
                "name": s_name
            }
        },
        "data":{
            "type": "file",
            "file": str(weburl + "/media/shapefiles/" + username + "/" + str(file_name))
        }
    }
}
r = requests.post(
    url + "/imports",
    data=json.dumps(data),
    auth=(admin, psswd),
    headers=headers
)
```

From the code above, I get a status code of `400`, the GeoServer logs show

```
2017-02-23 19:08:46,289 WARN [geoserver.security] - Could not find factory for store : DataStoreInfoImpl[kml1]. Unable to encrypt connection parameters.
2017-02-23 19:08:46,289 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded store 'kml1', disabled
2017-02-23 19:08:46,290 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - Target store does not exist : kml1
2017-02-23 19:08:46,290 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException
at org.geoserver.importer.rest.ImportResource.createImport(ImportResource.java:157)
at org.geoserver.importer.rest.ImportResource.handlePost(ImportResource.java:205)
at org.restlet.Finder.handle(Finder.java:296)
at org.geoserver.rest.BeanDelegatingRestlet.handle(BeanDelegatingRestlet.java:38)
at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:105)
at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:134)
at org.restlet.Router.handle(Router.java:444)
at org.geoserver.rest.RESTDispatcher$1.handle(RESTDispatcher.java:205)
at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletConverter.service(ServletConverter.java:129)
at org.geoserver.rest.RESTDispatcher.handleRequestInternal(RESTDispatcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
at com.boundlessgeo.geoserver.AppDispatcher.doDispatch(AppDispatcher.java:67)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at com.boundlessgeo.geoserver.AppAuthFilter.doFilter(AppAuthFilter.java:111)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-02-23 19:08:46,473 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such datastore: amallard,kml1
2017-02-23 19:08:46,473 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException
at org.geoserver.catalog.rest.DataStoreFinder.findTarget(DataStoreFinder.java:39)
at org.restlet.Finder.handle(Finder.java:268)
at org.geoserver.rest.BeanDelegatingRestlet.handle(BeanDelegatingRestlet.java:38)
at org.restlet.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:105)
at org.restlet.Filter.handle(Filter.java:134)
at org.restlet.Router.handle(Router.java:444)
at org.geoserver.rest.RESTDispatcher$1.handle(RESTDispatcher.java:205)
at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletConverter.service(ServletConverter.java:129)
at org.geoserver.rest.RESTDispatcher.handleRequestInternal(RESTDispatcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
at com.boundlessgeo.geoserver.AppDispatcher.doDispatch(AppDispatcher.java:67)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at com.boundlessgeo.geoserver.AppAuthFilter.doFilter(AppAuthFilter.java:111)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This seems like it's giving me the error, because I'm trying to upload a file into a location that hasn't been created yet. However, this is actually very similar to what we do when uploading the SHP files to GeoServer. I have tried to upload the KML through the default REST API much like how we already upload the SHP files, but the GeoServer logs give me an `unsupported type: kml` error.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I upload KML files to GeoServer?

Comment: Does it work if you upload by hand? Possibly not the REST API, but some other part of the geoserver instance configuration.

Comment: @BradHards see updated post. Is that what you mean?

Comment: So the problem is not in your REST call. Your KML and geoserver don't agree on structure.

Comment: @BradHards Is this a configuration setting then? I thought KML uploading was an out-of-the-box feature for the Importer Extension (Note: I did not install the extension, could the dev who installed it do something wrong perhaps?)

Comment: Could be, but unlikely. More likely your KML has something unusual about it. I'd suggest closing this question and starting another (reference back to this one for background, if you like).

Comment: @BradHards for some reason that KML file didn't work. I tried another KML file and was able to manually upload it. However, I still got the same error as before using the REST API

Comment: Suggest updating your question - the critical detail is about to get lost in comments...

Comment: The stack trace is incomplete and lacks the important bits, the kmls that do not work are also missing. Sorry, nothing that can be done with important details left out.

Comment: @AndreaAime I have included the full error log and the KML files I've tried.

Comment: @AndreaAime Someone told me on another forum (Boundless Connect) that there's an unresolved bug report for this issue, however upon looking at GeoServer Jira page, I didn't see one. Do you have any insight on this?